# Matplot multiple lines ploting in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

Everyone! I need to plot multiple lines using matplotlib (not necessarily) from four arrays in a single graph. Currently my code is

```
plt.plot(PTime,PReactions,NYTime,NYReactions,LTime,LReactions,SFTime,SFReactions)
plt.show()
```

PTime and PReactions are the name of the arrays and so on.
This is the output of the above code:

[image: This is the output of the above code]

But I don't want this type of graph. I want multiple lines representing different arrays (different data).
I want results something similar to this:

[image: I want results something similar to this]

Comment: Ususualy, you can browse the [Matplotlib Gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html), find an example that [has a feature you want](http://matplotlib.org/examples/style_sheets/plot_fivethirtyeight.html#style-sheets-example-code-plot-fivethirtyeight-py), figure out how they did it and then adapt.  There is also [the Pyplot tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html#pyplot-tutorial) and of course [the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) itself.

Comment: Can you provide a *minimal* example of two of your vectors?

Comment: Is it possible, that you have just strongly oscillating data and for this reason, you got the impression, that it is plotted as areas and not as lines?  If this is the case, just try zooming in a lot and probably you will be able to identify the seperate lines.

Comment: @MarkusDutschke this is not the case. The data is not oscillating. The horizontal line contains time in increasing sequencing and the vertical line contains number ranging form 0 to 3500. it contains data of every second of 7 days and every second contains some values which have been plotted here. The data which is being plotted here is large in number i.e. 0.6 Million on both axis. The data is stored in arrays and which is being plotted but he output is not what I want.

Comment: @wwii the horizontal axis contains the array of time and the vertical axis contains the some number as explained in the above comment.

Comment: You already have multiple lines representing different arrays. The Y axis of the second plot ranges from 0 to 0.005, you can't get that if yor data ranges from 0 to 3500. It looks like you just don't like your data but I don't think we can help you to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is presented in the wrong order. It must be `X, Y`:

```
plt.plot(PReactions, PTime)
plt.plot(NYReactions, NYTime)
plt.plot(LReactions, LTime)
plt.plot(SFReactions, SFTime)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The above code is working perfectly fine but I don't want the output it is generating. please see the images

Comment: Ah I see you issue. You have mixed up X and Y values, I suppose

Comment: No I didn't . The X and Y values are according to the logic. The current result is  https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzmUx.png this and I want https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0Okw.png this. can you help?

Comment: one thing I would like to add is that the length of the array is one lac minimum.

Comment: @HamidAli Can you go more into detail why this solution by languitar does not meat your requirement? Also clearly state which array you want as horizontal and vertical coordinates. And what makes your *how-it-should-look* picture different from waht you have? Is it the dates on the horizontal axis? Is it the colors that the values have?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes you are right. The horizontal axis contains time which is varying in seconds and is increasing order. And it contains the time of 7 days. The vertical line contains values from 0 to 3500. I don't know what is causing problem but the only thing is the size of the data which is being plotted here which is 0.6 Million. That may not be the cause but I don't know yet.

Comment: Then we need some part of the data to understand the issue. I don't think it is possible to replicate the issue without having a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

**minimal working example:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a=np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
b=np.linspace(0, 2, 10)
c=np.linspace(0, 3, 10)
d=np.linspace(0, 4, 10)

plt.plot(b,a)
plt.plot(c,a)
plt.plot(d,a)

plt.show()
```

**gives you:**

[image]

Comment: can you please suggest how will it work on array of large size? I mean I want to generate lines from arrays. Like if I have an "array" where would I put it in np.linespace?

Comment: sorry I do not get your question :(. a,b,c,d are arrays, as the function np.linspace returns arrays. a stores the x values and b,c,d store the y values. At the moment they have length 10, but you can increase that value.
Here is some python tutorial, which I strongly recommend you to do:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Comment: I have my own arrays. no need to use np.linspace. how will it work ?